# DnD-like Fight (Single Round)

Tags: java

### Let's Fight:

one `Entity` can perform an attack (thus making him an *attacker*) on another `Entity` (*defender*). This follows some *Rules*, described within the `AttackProcedure.performAttack()`. The `FightRules` describe, what `Chances` one `Entity` has to succeed (or not) and what Damage will results from an attack.

[image]

(C) https://www.pinclipart.com/pindetail/omwhRx_knight-knight-fight-icon-clipart/

Can you please Review this code?

### Code

**Stat:**

```
public class Stat {

    private Object identifier;
    private double base;
    private double current;


    public Stat(Object identifier, double base, int current) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
        this.base = base;
        this.current = current;
    }

    public Object getIdentifier() {
        return identifier;
    }

    public void apply(StatChange change) {
        current = current + change.getDelta();
    }

    public double getCurrent() {
        return current;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return identifier + " " + current + " / " + base;
    }

}
```

**Stats:**

```
public interface Stats {

    Stat getStat(Object identifier);

    void changeStats(List<StatChange> impact);

}
```

**StatChange:**

```
public class StatChange {

    private final Object identifier;
    private final double delta;

    public StatChange(Object identifier, double delta) {
        this.identifier = Objects.requireNonNull(identifier, "identifier must not be null");
        this.delta = delta;
    }

    public boolean matches(Stat stat) {
        return identifier.equals(stat.getIdentifier());
    }

    public double getDelta() {
        return delta;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" + identifier + " delta:" + delta;
    }
}
```

**Chance:**

```
public interface Chance {

    boolean wasSuccessful();

    String getRollResult();
}
```

**FightRules:**

```
public interface FightRules<I extends Chance, E extends Entity> {

    I getAttackChance(E attacker, E defender);

    I getDefendChance(E attacker, E defender);

    List<StatChange> getImpact(E attacker, E defender, I attackChance, I defendChance);

}
```

**Entity:**

```
public interface Entity {

    Stats getStats();

}
```

**AttackProcedure:**

```
public class AttackProcedure {

    private final FightRules rules;

    public AttackProcedure(FightRules rules) {
        this.rules = rules;
    }

    public Result performAttack(Entity attacker, Entity defender) {
        AttackProcedureResult result = new AttackProcedureResult();
        result.logIntro(attacker, defender);

        Chance attackChance = rules.getAttackChance(attacker, defender);
        Chance defendChance = rules.getDefendChance(attacker, defender);

        result.logAttackChance(attackChance);

        if (attackChance.wasSuccessful()) {
            result.logAttackSucceeded(defendChance);
            if (defendChance.wasSuccessful()) {
                result.logDefendSucceeded();
            } else {
                result.logDefendFailed();
                applyDamage(attacker, defender, attackChance, defendChance, result);
            }
        } else {
            result.logAttackFailed();
        }
        result.logOutro(attacker, defender);
        return result;
    }

    private void applyDamage(Entity attacker, Entity defender, Chance attackChance, Chance defendChance, AttackProcedureResult result) {
        List<StatChange> impact = rules.getImpact(attacker, defender, attackChance, defendChance);
        result.logImpact(impact);
        defender.getStats().changeStats(impact);
    }

}
```

**Result:**

```
public interface Result {

    void append(String line);

    List<String> entries();
}
```

**AttackProcedureResult:**

```
public class AttackProcedureResult implements Result {

    private final List<String> log = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void append(String line) {
        log.add(line);
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> entries() {
        return log;
    }

    void logAttackSucceeded(Chance defendChance) {
        append("attack was successful (attacker hit)");
        append("chance of successful block the attack is: " + defendChance);
        append("defender rolled: " + defendChance.getRollResult() + ", defense was successful=" + defendChance.wasSuccessful());
        append("");
    }

    void logOutro(Entity attacker, Entity defender) {
        append("");
        append("attack is done, " + attacker + ", " + defender);
        append("--------");
        append("");
    }

    void logAttackChance(Chance attackChance) {
        append("chance of successful attack is: " + attackChance);
        append("attacker rolled: " + attackChance.getRollResult() + ", attack was successful=" + attackChance.wasSuccessful());
        append("");
    }

    void logIntro(Entity attacker, Entity defender) {
        append("attack begins");
        append(attacker + " attacks " + defender);
        append("--------");
        append("");
    }

    void logDefendSucceeded() {
        append("defender successfully avoided the attack");
    }

    void logDefendFailed() {
        append("defender could not avoid the attack - time to take some damage....");
    }

    void logAttackFailed() {
        append("attack was not successful (attacker missed)");
    }

    void logImpact(List<StatChange> impact) {
        append("giving impact: " + impact);
    }
}
```

### Tests

**AttackProcedureTest:**

```
public class AttackProcedureTest {

    private final AttackProcedure attackProcedure = new AttackProcedure(new TestFightRules());
    private TestEntity attacker = new TestEntity("attacker");

    @Test
    public void test_successfulAttack_withFailingDefense_procedureExecution() {
        //given
        TestEntity defender = new TestEntity("defender");
        attacker.setSupposedToSucceedInAttack(true);
        defender.setSupposedToSucceedInDefense(false);
        double defenderLifeBefore = defender.getStats().getStat(TestStatIdentifier.HEALTH).getCurrent();

        //when
        Result result = attackProcedure.performAttack(attacker, defender);
        result.entries().forEach(System.out::println);
        double defenderLifeAfter = defender.getStats().getStat(TestStatIdentifier.HEALTH).getCurrent();

        //then
        assertEquals(1, defenderLifeBefore, 0.01);
        assertEquals(0, defenderLifeAfter, 0.01);
        assertNotNull(result);
        assertFalse(result.entries().isEmpty());
    }

    @Test
    public void test_failingAttack_ProcedureExecution() {
        //given
        TestEntity defender = new TestEntity("defender");
        attacker.setSupposedToSucceedInAttack(false);
        defender.setSupposedToSucceedInDefense(false);
        double defenderLifeBefore = defender.getStats().getStat(TestStatIdentifier.HEALTH).getCurrent();

        //when
        Result result = attackProcedure.performAttack(attacker, defender);
        result.entries().forEach(System.out::println);
        double defenderLifeAfter = defender.getStats().getStat(TestStatIdentifier.HEALTH).getCurrent();

        //then
        assertEquals(1, defenderLifeBefore, 0.01);
        assertEquals(1, defenderLifeAfter, 0.01);
        assertNotNull(result);
        assertFalse(result.entries().isEmpty());
    }

    @Test
    public void test_successfulAttack_withSuccessfulDefense_procedureExecution() {
        //given
        TestEntity defender = new TestEntity("defender");
        attacker.setSupposedToSucceedInAttack(true);
        defender.setSupposedToSucceedInDefense(true);
        double defenderLifeBefore = defender.getStats().getStat(TestStatIdentifier.HEALTH).getCurrent();

        //when
        Result result = attackProcedure.performAttack(attacker, defender);
        result.entries().forEach(System.out::println);
        double defenderLifeAfter = defender.getStats().getStat(TestStatIdentifier.HEALTH).getCurrent();

        //then
        assertEquals(1, defenderLifeBefore, 0.01);
        assertEquals(1, defenderLifeAfter, 0.01);
        assertNotNull(result);
        assertFalse(result.entries().isEmpty());
    }

}
```

**TestEntity:**

```
public class TestEntity implements Entity {

    private final String name;
    private final Stats stats = new TestStats();
    private boolean isSupposedToSucceedInAttack;
    private boolean isSupposedToSucceedInDefense;

    public TestEntity(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public Stats getStats() {
        return stats;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " " + getStats().getStat(TestStatIdentifier.HEALTH);
    }

    public boolean isSupposedToSucceedInAttack() {
        return isSupposedToSucceedInAttack;
    }

    public void setSupposedToSucceedInAttack(boolean supposedToSucceedInAttack) {
        isSupposedToSucceedInAttack = supposedToSucceedInAttack;
    }

    public boolean isSupposedToSucceedInDefense() {
        return isSupposedToSucceedInDefense;
    }

    public void setSupposedToSucceedInDefense(boolean supposedToSucceedInDefense) {
        isSupposedToSucceedInDefense = supposedToSucceedInDefense;
    }
}
```

**TestFightRules:**

```
public class TestFightRules implements FightRules<Chance, TestEntity> {

    @Override
    public Chance getAttackChance(TestEntity attacker, TestEntity defender) {
        if (attacker.isSupposedToSucceedInAttack()) {
            return new WinningChance();
        }
        return new FailingChance();
    }

    @Override
    public Chance getDefendChance(TestEntity attacker, TestEntity defender) {
        if (defender.isSupposedToSucceedInDefense()) {
            return new WinningChance();
        }
        return new FailingChance();
    }

    @Override
    public List<StatChange> getImpact(TestEntity attacker, TestEntity defender, Chance attackChance, Chance defendChance) {
        return Collections.singletonList(new StatChange(TestStatIdentifier.HEALTH, -1));
    }
}
```

**TestWinningChance:**

```
public class WinningChance implements Chance {

    private final int die;

    public WinningChance() {
        die = 1 + new Random().nextInt(20);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean wasSuccessful() {
        return die < 23;
    }

    @Override
    public String getRollResult() {
        return "1D20=" + die;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "succeed if 1D20 < 23";
    }
}
```

**TestFailingChance:**

```
public class FailingChance implements Chance {

    private final int die;

    public FailingChance() {
        die = 1 + new Random().nextInt(20);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean wasSuccessful() {
        return die < 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getRollResult() {
        return "1D20=" + die;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "succeed if 1D20 < 0";
    }
}
```

**TestStats:**

```
public class TestStats implements Stats {

    private final List<Stat> collection;

    public TestStats() {
        collection = new ArrayList<>();
        collection.add(new Stat(TestStatIdentifier.HEALTH, 1, 1));
    }

    @Override
    public Stat getStat(Object identifier) {
        return collection.stream().filter(s -> s.getIdentifier().equals(identifier)).findAny().orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void changeStats(List<StatChange> impact) {
        for (Stat stat : collection) {
            for (StatChange change : impact) {
                if (change.matches(stat)) {
                    stat.apply(change);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**TestStatIdentifier:**

```
public enum TestStatIdentifier {

    HEALTH, INTELLIGENCE, STRENGTH

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I compared the class `Stat`:

> ```
> public class Stat {
>     private Object identifier;
>     private double base;
>     private double current;
>     .....methods
> }
> ```

and the class `TestStats` using it:

> ```
> public class TestStats implements Stats {
>     private final List<Stat> collection;
>     public TestStats() {
>         collection = new ArrayList<>();
>         collection.add(new Stat(TestStatIdentifier.HEALTH, 1, 1));
>     }
>     @Override
>     public Stat getStat(Object identifier) {
>         return collection.stream().filter(s -> s.getIdentifier().equals(identifier)).findAny().orElse(null);
>     }
> }
> ```

You are implementing with your two classes a `Map<String, Stat>` because you a direct corrispondence between the name of your stat and the couple of doubles `base` and `current` present in your class `Stat`. The `Object` field `identifier` is used a key in the map, so you can rewrite your `Stat` class in this way:

```
public class Stat {
    private double base;
    private double current;

    public Stat(double base, int current) {
        this.base = base;
        this.current = current;
    }

    public void apply(StatChange change) {
        current += change.getDelta();
    }

    public double getCurrent() {
        return current;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%.1f/%.1f", current, base);
    }
}
```

Now your class TestStats will contain a `Map<String, Stat>` and this seems logic to me because every fighter (`Entity`) has its map of characteristics defined when you initialize the fighter:

```
public class TestStats implements Stats {
    private final Map<String, Stat> map;

    public TestStats(Map<String, Stat> map) {
        this.map = new TreeMap<>(map);
    }

    @Override
    public Stat getStat(String identifier) {
        return map.getOrDefault(identifier, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void changeStats(List<StatChange> impact) {
        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
            for (StatChange change : impact) {
                if (change.matches(key)) {
                    map.get(key).apply(change);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Consequently there are some minor changes to `Stats` interface and `StatChange`:

```
public interface Stats {
    Stat getStat(String identifier);
    void changeStats(List<StatChange> impact);
}
```

and StatChange class:

```
public class StatChange {
    private final String name;
    private final double delta;

    public StatChange(String identifier, double delta) {
        this.name = Objects.requireNonNull(identifier, "identifier must not be null");
        this.delta = delta;
    }

    public boolean matches(String identifier) {
        return name.equals(identifier);
    }

    public double getDelta() {
        return delta;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s delta:%.1f", name, delta);
    }
}
```

Some changes can be applied to your `AttackProcedureTest` class : you can use the annotation `@Before` to a `setUp` method that will be invoked before every test to initialize the scenarios, you class could be rewritten in this way:

```
public class AttackProcedureTest {
    private final AttackProcedure attackProcedure = new AttackProcedure(new TestFightRules());
    private final static String HEALTH = "HEALTH";
    private TestEntity attacker;
    private TestEntity defender;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        Map<String , Stat> map = new HashMap<String, Stat>();
        map.put(HEALTH, new Stat(1, 1));
        attacker = new TestEntity("attacker", new TestStats(map));
        defender = new TestEntity("defender", new TestStats(map));
    }

    @Test
    public void test_successfulAttack_withFailingDefense_procedureExecution() {
        double defenderLifeBefore = defender.getStats().getStat(HEALTH).getCurrent();

        attacker.setSupposedToSucceedInAttack(true);
        defender.setSupposedToSucceedInDefense(false);
        Result result = attackProcedure.performAttack(attacker, defender);
        result.entries().forEach(System.out::println);

        double defenderLifeAfter = defender.getStats().getStat(HEALTH).getCurrent();

        assertEquals(1, defenderLifeBefore, 0.01);
        assertEquals(0, defenderLifeAfter, 0.01);
        assertNotNull(result);
        assertFalse(result.entries().isEmpty());
    }

    @Test
    public void test_failingAttack_ProcedureExecution() {
        double defenderLifeBefore = defender.getStats().getStat(HEALTH).getCurrent();

        attacker.setSupposedToSucceedInAttack(false);
        defender.setSupposedToSucceedInDefense(false);
        Result result = attackProcedure.performAttack(attacker, defender);
        result.entries().forEach(System.out::println);

        double defenderLifeAfter = defender.getStats().getStat(HEALTH).getCurrent();

        assertEquals(1, defenderLifeBefore, 0.01);
        assertEquals(1, defenderLifeAfter, 0.01);
        assertNotNull(result);
        assertFalse(result.entries().isEmpty());
    }

    @Test
    public void test_successfulAttack_withSuccessfulDefense_procedureExecution() {
        double defenderLifeBefore = defender.getStats().getStat(HEALTH).getCurrent();

        attacker.setSupposedToSucceedInAttack(true);
        defender.setSupposedToSucceedInDefense(true);        
        Result result = attackProcedure.performAttack(attacker, defender);
        result.entries().forEach(System.out::println);

        double defenderLifeAfter = defender.getStats().getStat(HEALTH).getCurrent();

        assertEquals(1, defenderLifeBefore, 0.01);
        assertEquals(1, defenderLifeAfter, 0.01);
        assertNotNull(result);
        assertFalse(result.entries().isEmpty());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you dariosicily for having a look at my code - i read your answer on my code already yesterday and honstely you found a very interesting point! i spend all night on overthinking how and where the identifier is supposed to be and i cannot tell you yet. Your answer provides a great idea on how my code coud be organized in another way. Thanks for sharing these thoughts with me!

Comment: @MartinFrank, You are welcome, my idea is the stats identifier is the `String` name of the stat, so if you extract it from the class and use it as a key in the `Map` stats the initialization of an `Entity` is simpler and because a map cannot contain duplicate keys you avoid the risk to duplicate the stats.

Comment: it would work as well if you would use the `TestStatIdentifier` as key as well - i would consider using a `String` as key would be slightly [Primitive-Obession](https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession)... but thats only my thinking